# Why does word completion not work in Mail?

Tags: macos, keyboard, mail.app

If I remember correctly Mail had the possibility of showing a word completion list as described [here](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20031019214026732) when you type a word partially and press <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd>.
Now this function has stopped working in Mail, and I don't understand why.
If I try the same in TextEdit or the Safari address bar it still works.
How can I restore this functionality in Mail in the first place?
Or have I been dreaming and was this functionality never present in Mail?

I'm on Mountain Lion 10.8.5 with Mail 6.6. I don't have any Mail plugins installed.

Comment: Option-esc works for me in Mail in 10.9 and 10.8, so it might be something specific to your installation.

Comment: Thanks for checking. How do I find out where the culprit is? Any configuration files that I can delete such that they're rebuild again?

Comment: It might be a .plist file in your user acct.  Try setting up another account and see if it works when you are logged in there.  You can trash .plist files without problem except that for Mail settings for servers may be lost.

Comment: I've boiled it down to one draft message. Every time I open that message (which is written in Cyrillic) the completion functionality ceases to exist. A restart of Mail.app solves the problem. When I write a new message in Cyrillic the completion works, it's only this one specific message.